# Delay Spring Boot application start

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've got a custom event and I'd like my Spring Boot application start after it is published.

This event is only published when the profile `foobar` is active. If it is not, Spring Boot application should launch as usual.

Can I do that?

UPDATE:

Suppose that profile `foobar` is active. In that case the `FoobarClass` component is initialized (`@Profile("foobar")`).

In the `FoobarClass.java` there's a `@PostConstruct` method.

```
@PostConstruct
public void postInit() {
    // some code
    launchSpringAppEvent.publishEvent("All done! Spring app can be launched now.");
}
```

The event is published and that would indicate the app is ready to be opened for users.

Comment: Can you add more details? The current question is unclear.

Comment: Hi @MaksimEliseev I've given an example

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear, but I bet you may want to use powerful Spring's event-driven capabilities, combined with Spring Boot's profile management, kinda:

1. Define your custom event:

```
public class CustomApplicationReadyEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    public CustomApplicationReadyEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }
}
```

2. Publish when your desired profile is active:

```
@Component
public class CustomEventPublisher implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active:}")
    private String activeProfile;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if ("foobar".equals(activeProfile)) {
            context.publishEvent(new CustomApplicationReadyEvent(this));
        }
    }
}
```

3. Consume & make what you want right in the listner

```
@Component
public class CustomEventListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handleCustomEvent(CustomApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        // your main logic here
    }
}
```

Just note that the Spring context itself will still initialize beans and perform its standard lifecycle, so you may "delay" your own custom logic only

Comment: Thanks for your response. I realize my question might have been too vague: I've updated the main post with the example. Wouldn't your code execute the specific-to-profile logic AFTER the Spring Application is run? The opposite is of interest to me. First publish the event, then do some logic and finally launch app.

Comment: Just wondering, what do you mean under the "finally launch app" statement? You won't be able to use profiles, events, and any other springish-stuff until your beans are not configured and injected

Comment: By launching app I mean that user can interact with it (API, GUI, etc.). I know that I can create a bean that would achieve that, but at first I was not so convinced that it is the right solution, but now I think that's OK to use a bean as a "initializer". After all, there's `DataSourceInitializer` for example.